# MathKernel launches only from /usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM

Tags: licensing

If go in the folder `/usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM` I can launch MathKernel no problem.
If I go anywhere else it complains it has not license.

In the folder `/usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM`  there is also the mathpass file, so this makes me confident that its content is correct. Indeed if I put a symlink to /usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM/mathpass in another folder MathKernel works if launched from that folder.

Any suggestion why it is not working? how should I fix this?

`mathlm` seems to be running fine according to `ps aux | grep mathlm`

```
ps aux | grep mathlm
user    56076  0.0  0.0   3940  2944 ?        S    13:38   0:00 /usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM/mathlm -logfile /home/user/MathLMlog
roberto    59945  0.0  0.0   6404  2308 pts/113  S+   13:55   0:00 grep --color=auto mathlm
```

The logfile does not show any error. It has entries for the times I have successfully launched MathKernel from the same path of a mathpass file

```
host - user [12/May/2023:17:43:35] "Kernel License requested" "License #1 granted" -
host - user [12/May/2023:17:45:22] "Kernel License returned" "License #1 accepted" -
host - user [12/May/2023:17:53:36] "Kernel License requested" "License #1 granted" -
host - user [12/May/2023:17:55:22] "Kernel License returned" "License #1 accepted" -
```

*SOLUTION* [This](https://support.wolfram.com/25655) article describes in what locations the `mathpass` is sought for. Strangely enough these do not include the location of `mathlm` nor the installer of MathLM puts it one of these locations by default.

Comment: The mathpass file used by MathLM is not the one you should use for the Kernel.   The mathpass file for the kernel should just contain `!<your_server_name_here>`.

Comment: My mathpass file starts with `!host` and has the rest of licensing info in that line. What's wrong with that? Where is this documented?

Comment: `/usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM/mathpass` should look like this `!hostname       AAAA-BBBBB-CCCCC        XXXX-YYYY-ZZZZZZ        1111-111-111:4:::CB`.  `~/.Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass` should look like this `!hostname`.

Comment: my `/usr/local/Wolfram/MathLM/mathpass` does look like you said. Sadly, this location is not a location where mathpass should be if you want to launch MathKernel from any path. Just in case you missed it, the [support page link](https://support.wolfram.com/25655) I have put in the question say that in Linux "The mathpass file is located at one of the following locations:"     `/usr/share/Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass`
    `~/.Mathematica/Licensing/mathpass`
    `/usr/local/Wolfram/Mathematica/Configuration/Licensing/mathpass`

Comment: If you have a mathpass file for MathLM, why are you trying to launch the kernel using it's password file?  That kinda defeats the purpose of MathLM, which is network licensing.  As in, you can have a MathLM with 10 licenses and bounce from machine to machine without having to activate them individually.  That is why the second mathpass entry is different, it is specifying the server that should be contacted to request a license from.